# Unable to get latitude and longitude of the US map from TopoJSON's us-atlas repository when using GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, centroids

To do some geospatial analysis I am using the USA [counties map](https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas#counties-10m.json) from [topojson/us-atlas repository](https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas)

After loading the link https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-10m.json in geopandas I get the geodataframe correctly.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
counties = gpd.read_file('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/counties-10m.json')
```

Then I just do the following to get the longitude and latitude -

```py
counties['lon'] = counties['geometry'].centroid.x
counties['lat'] = counties['geometry'].centroid.y
```

But I get the error -

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Only the `centroid` attribute seems to give the output :
`counties['geometry'].centroid` gives -

```
0       POINT (-113.75823 35.70499)
1        POINT (-90.40498 30.62627)
2       POINT (-114.13825 43.00235)
3        POINT (-96.40159 47.77421)
4        POINT (-97.24835 46.93312)
```

Any idea how to get the longitude and latitude of the counties / states from the us-atlas file?

Comment: Is it possible that you have missing geometry somewhere? Or invalid? That could cause the error.

Comment: @martinfleis Ummm....but if i had missing geometry then calling just `centroid` too would have given error right? I plotted the raw data and it worked, so I figured that atleast the geometries are alright. But I not so sure. Maybe you can check since the file is there in topojson's repository.

Comment: No, centroid gives `None` in that case. You can check with `counties.geometry.isna().any()`, `counties.geometry.is_empty().any()` and `counties.geometry.is_valid().any()`.

Comment: I see. When I tried `counties.geometry.isna().any()` I get False. But the rest give the same error ```TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable```

Comment: Of sorry, those are properties, so without `()`. As `counties.geometry.is_empty.any()`

Comment: Oh. Yeah after that I get True for both of them. That means I do have some rows where the geometry is not present right? So just filtering them will do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `IndexError` of this kind if the GeoSeries with centroid does contain empty geometry.

You have to check if all geometries are valid and non-empty.

```py
counties.geometry.is_empty.any()

counties.geometry.is_valid.any()
```

If you get True for any of those, you will have to drop affected rows. On of the options is below.

```py
empty = counties.geometry.is_empty

counties_non_empty = counties[~empty]

counties_non_empty['lon'] = counties_non_empty['geometry'].centroid.x
counties_non_empty['lat'] = counties_non_empty['geometry'].centroid.y
```